# Python gives same index for same words. How can i differentiate between two words?

Tags: python

I am comparing a string with itself to see if duplicate words exist in the same string.

I am using indices to differentiate the words but i am getting no output since python considers both the words to have same value and same address. I got no output with this code. (Please don't suggest range(len(x+1)) method, since I want to use this particular way of comparison

```
input= "The hello hello substring string of this pan is amazing hello"
x=input.split(" ")

for i in x:
    for j in x:
        if x.index(i)!=x.index(j) and i==j:
            print(i,x.index(i),j,x.index(j))
```

I was expecting something like

hello,1,hello,2,hello,10

but in python memory it's

hello,1,hello,1,hello,1

so it doesn't give any output. How can it have same index when they are at different locations in the sentence

Comment: What do `list.index` docs say?

Comment: if `i==j` then it cannot be that `x.index(i)!=x.index(j)`  you have some mistake in your logic. Also naming a variable `input` is not a good idea, since it will shadow the builtin function `input`.  Could you also explain your output? why do you expect hello,1,hello,10  and not hello,1,hello,2,hello,10 ?

Comment: Why are you expecting "hello,1,hello,10" and not "hello,1,hello,2,hello,10" ?

Comment: I missed it while typing, infact i am expecting hello,1,hello,2,hello,10

Answer (score 0):

Your ideas work but you did not implement them correctly. `x.index['hello']` returns the first (and only first) appearance of that word in the list. It does not allow you to look for additional occurences (at least without providing the `start` argument to only look form the start index onwards).
You can use:

```
input_string= "The hello hello substring string of this pan is amazing hello"
x=input_string.split(" ")

for i, first_word in enumerate(x):
    for j, second_word in enumerate(x):
        if j <= i:
            continue
        if first_word==second_word:
            print(i, first_word, j, second_word)
```

Note that this is not the most efficient way to implement this for long strings but probably completely fine for your application. A lookup dict (c.f. answer from @CtrlZ) would be faster but only for very long strings.

Comment: This does not produce the required output

Comment: I would say that "I was expecting something like ..." does not clearly define a required output. You are right, that my output differs from that, I was focusing on staying somewhat close to OPs original code for didactive reasons.

Comment: I don't think that teaching someone to use unnecessary nested loops is a good thing. Your inner loop is entered 121 times whereas you could use two (not nested) loops for a total of just 22 iterations

Comment: It depends on whether speed is actually more important than legibility in the use case. Using a dict just for the O(n) time complexity is not even useful for small n. On my machine, your code is even slower than mine.

Comment: What machine and Python version are you using? On Apple Silicon (M2) and with Python 3.12.1 my code runs in half the time of yours despite producing more complex output. If you want me to help you with how to test Python performance I'm happy to enter into a dialogue with you

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to build a dictionary keyed on the words and with values that are lists containing the indexes of where the word (key) occurs in the original string.

Something like this:

```
s = "The hello hello substring string of this pan is amazing hello"

d = dict()

for i, word in enumerate(s.split()):
    d.setdefault(word, []).append(i)

for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(*(f"{k},{i}" for i in v), sep=",")
```

**Output:**

```
hello,1,hello,2,hello,10
```

Answer (score 0):

other answers work but this is kind of a fun one, here is a solution using what i feel is nicer logic:

```
s = "The hello hello substring string of this pan is amazing hello"
words = s.split()
unique_words = set(words)
output = {word:[] for word in unique_words}

for word in unique_words:
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] == word:
           output[word].append(i)
print(output)
```

this outputs:

`{'hello': [1, 2, 10], 'pan': [7], 'amazing': [9], 'string': [4], 'is': [8], 'this': [6], 'substring': [3], 'of': [5], 'The': [0]}`

Comment: See my answer for a more efficient way to build the dictionary